# onClick in anchor tag triggers without clicking in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

This is the function I call to add PageItems to my page.

```
function PageItems (props)
  var pageItems = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < props.noOfPages; i++) {
    pageItems.push(
      <li className="page-item" key={uuid.v4()}>
        <a className="page-link" onClick={props.onClick(i+1)}>{i+1}</a>
      </li>
    );
  }
  return (
    <ul className="pagination justify-content-center">
      {pageItems}
    </ul> 
  );
}
```

My render function inside the class

```
render () {
  const recipes = this.props.recipes;
  const totalRecipes = recipes.length;
  const noOfPages = totalRecipes % 3 === 0 ? totalRecipes / 3 : Math.floor(totalRecipes / 3) + 1;
  //console.log(totalRecipes, noOfPages);
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid viewRecipes">
      <nav>
        <PageItems noOfPages={noOfPages} currPageNo={this.state.currPageNo} onClick={this.handlePagination} />
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem here is whenever my page loads the `handlePagination` (which right now only console.logs the value passed to it) function automatically gets triggered (**I'm binding the function in my constructor**). Add on clicking the links nothing new consoles. 
Please help me with this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
props.onClick(i+1)
```

This calls the function and assigns the returned value to the `<a>` tags onClick handler. To get a function instead, do this:

```
props.onClick.bind(this, i+1)
```

`bind()` creates a new function which calls the original one with the given `this` context and parameters. If `props.onClick()` accepts more parameters, the new function takes the same parameters.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But could you please explain why this happens? Actually I'm fairly new to React. I can understand why we bind a normal class. But not this, as `PageItems` is a function itself then why are we required to bind `this` here also.

Comment: @HemakshiSachdev I tried to explain in my answer, but perhaps did not do well enough. There are two issues here: 1. Your original code calls the `props.onClick()` method **immediately** in the `render()` function and assigns its return value to the `<a>` tag's onClick handler. This is why it appears to fire `onClick()` without clicking on the link.

Comment: @HemakshiSachdev 2. You want to assign a function to the `onClick` handler instead. Since you need to pass in an argument to `props.onClick()`, you need to call use `bind`. `bind` returns a new function with some of the parameters passed in already. This is called "partial application". For more details I suggest you google these words.

Answer (score 1):

Your onClick in the PageItem li isn't a function reference. You could either bind the function as @Code-Apprentice pointed out, or do:

```
    <a className="page-link" onClick={(e) => props.onClick(i+1)}>{i+1}</a>
```